# self() as function within class, what does it do?

Tags: python, pytorch

Sorry for the poor title but I'm unsure how better to describe the question.

So I recently watched Andrej Kaparthy's build GPT video which is awesome and now trying to reconstruct the code myself I notices that he uses self() as a function and was curious why and what exactly it does.

The code is here and I'm curious in particular about the generate function:

```
class BigramLanguageModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size):
        super().__init__()
        # each token directly reads off the logits for the next token from a lookup table
        self.token_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):

        # idx and targets are both (B,T) tensor of integers
        logits = self.token_embedding_table(idx) # (B,T,C)

        if targets is None:
            loss = None
        else:
            B, T, C = logits.shape
            logits = logits.view(B*T, C)
            targets = targets.view(B*T)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, targets)

        return logits, loss

    def generate(self, idx, max_new_tokens):
        # idx is (B, T) array of indices in the current context
        for _ in range(max_new_tokens):
            # get the predictions
            logits, loss = self(idx)
            # focus only on the last time step
            logits = logits[:, -1, :] # becomes (B, C)
            # apply softmax to get probabilities
            probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1) # (B, C)
            # sample from the distribution
            idx_next = torch.multinomial(probs, num_samples=1) # (B, 1)
            # append sampled index to the running sequence
            idx = torch.cat((idx, idx_next), dim=1) # (B, T+1)
        return idx
```

So to me it seems that he is calling the forward function defined within the class through using the self(). Is that correct? And if so why would he not use `forward(idx)` instead. Thank you for you help!

Comment: What is `nn`? ...

Comment: `self` is an instance of the class. It is *calling the instance*. That is it. Presumably, the instance is callable. Since you don't define a `__call__` method, then we can only surmise it is inherited.

Comment: " Is that correct? " Possibly, there is no way to tell without giving us the complete code, it's whatever the `__call__` method does.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga full code is here: https://github.com/karpathy/ng-video-lecture/blob/master/bigram.py

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see the __call__ being defined anywhere hence added confusion thanks for your help!

Comment: Meh, the call is already inhered the from nn.Module

Comment: @TheEngineerProgrammer ah ok this makes sense. Although I appreciate there might be some difference I like your intuitive explanation sad the question has been closed already.

Comment: @IloveR if you look at my last comment, I linked to exactly where it is defined in the github repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meh, this is pytorch. Remember that you can use the model like this: `model(x)` to do the `model.forward(x)`. So inside of the model class `self(x)` will be the basically the same as doing `self.forward(x)`.

Comment: [That's not going to be exactly equivalent](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b04f86363fce9828b066ee516e78912691129b3f/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1494)

Comment: Yes not 100% the same, but in pytorch this will be practically the same.

Comment: Well, no, because `model(x)` will invoke hooks if they exist but `model.forward(x)` won't.

Comment: I already told you, they are not 100% the same, model(x) will also do some checks, but in practical, 99.99% of the cases in pytorch they are interchangeable.